# AWS APIGateway Image not shown

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway

I created a API Gateway which is Integrated to use S3 bucket. I see that when I tried to retrieve the object I am getting a 200 response. However I am getting some ackward text(probably a base64 or binary text rather than the image. Can you please let me know the fix.

[image]

Comment: what is the URL of the API? how are you calling the API?

Comment: I am calling the URL from postman client or node js client. None of them works.

Comment: Try browsing the url directly from the browser? postman can not show the image as image...

Comment: I tried no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is set the following headers:-
[image]